# pixelview bt878 card not being recognized

Tags: linux, video

I'm having huge difficulties with using Pixelview pv-bt878p+ rev.9d with Linux. I'm using a stock Debian kernel, version 3.2.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP.

When I load bttv module for that card I get this:

```
[  683.700105] bttv: 0: unloading
[  690.772928] bttv: driver version 0.9.19 loaded
[  690.772941] bttv: using 8 buffers with 2080k (520 pages) each for capture
[  690.773719] bttv: Bt8xx card found (0)
[  690.773767] bttv: 0: Bt878 (rev 17) at 0000:00:0f.0, irq: 12, latency: 64, mmio: 0xcfdfe000
[  690.773817] bttv: 0: using:  *** UNKNOWN/GENERIC ***  [card=0,autodetected]
[  690.775504] tveeprom 0-0050: Huh, no eeprom present (err=-6)?
[  690.775516] bttv: 0: tuner type unset
[  690.777636] bttv: 0: registered device video0
[  690.779489] bttv: 0: registered device vbi0
```

I know I can add some options to the module, so I've been trying with such:

```
modprobe bttv  card=72 tuner=38 radio=1 gpiomask=0x3F audiomux=33,32,35,35,40
```

and

```
modprobe bttv  card=70 tuner=38 radio=1 gpiomask=0x3F audiomux=33,32,35,35,40
```

Which I've found somewhere on the internet, and it fixed one's problems with similar card. For me it was unsuccessful.

lspci for that card gives me this:

```
00:0f.0 Multimedia video controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Video Capture (rev 11)
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 12
        Memory at cfdfe000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [44] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [4c] Power Management version 2
        Kernel driver in use: bttv

00:0f.1 Multimedia controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture (rev 11)
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 12
        Memory at cfdff000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [44] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [4c] Power Management version 2
```

Perhaps some of you know how could I progress in my endeavour to start using this card under linux?

Comment: I don't think this belongs here (Are you using this device for some work purpose?), and even if it technically does you might get better answers over on SuperUser or Unix & Linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=900899), where is reported this recommended values:

```
card=37 tuner=6
```

Comment: I've tried this, but my card didn't like it. So since this works for some people I'll accept this answer anyway

Comment: I've tried to search in official documentation (BTTV HOWTO), and parameters, which you are using, seems to be correct (I don't know about parameter for tuner). Can you, please, post a dmesg output, when you try modprobe with parameters `card=72 tuner=38`? What is the sign on the tuner chip? `tuner=38` parameter is for Philips PAL/SECAM multi (FM1216ME MK3). On the chip you would have 'FM1216ME MK3'.